# Placement Target is null all the time

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a context menu for a button like this:

```
<Button x:Name="btnView" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
        AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=DataContext}"
    <Button.ContextMenu >
        <ContextMenu x:Name="contextMenu" 
                     DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >
            <MenuItem Header="View" Command="{Binding CommandObj.ViewCommand}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

The ViewCommand is not triggered when I click the menu item. When I check the Placement Target is null. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What makes you think that your `PlacementTarget` value is `null`? You can't tell that from the XAML. Otherwise, it seems as though you are correctly passing the `DataContext` value through to the `ContextMenu` correctly. Perhaps your `Binding` in the `Tag` property is incorrect?

Comment: @user3668639 how do you check it? `PlacementTarget` won't be set until popup is open. Have you confirmed that `Tag`, and later `DataContext`, is set to what you expect and it has `CommandObj` property?

Comment: okay..i didn't know that PlacementTarget is not set until the pop up is open. I have another button which is binded directly to the DataContext of the user control, that is working fine.So i think there is no problem with the Tag and the DataContext.

Comment: `DataContext` of `ContextMenu` is set fine also `Tag` binding seems OK  (assuming that this the object you want) so I would guess problem is here `Command="{Binding CommandObj.ViewCommand}"`. Does it have `CommandObj` property? Did you try, for debugging, changing `Header="{Binding}"` and see what will happen? By default it should display type name of `DataContext`

Comment: Also, have you tired putting a breakpoint in the `CanExecute` section of your `ICommand`... if your `ICommand` is data bound correctly, the breakpoint should be hit when you open the `ContextMenu`.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your `ViewCommand ICommand` to work, a number of things have to be true regarding your XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="btnView" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
        AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=DataContext}"
    <Button.ContextMenu >
        <ContextMenu x:Name="contextMenu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
            <MenuItem Header="View" Command="{Binding CommandObj.ViewCommand}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

1. You have to have already set an instance of an object to the `UserControl.DataContext` property.
2. That object has to have a public property named `CommandObj` declared in it.
3. The `CommandObj` property must be of a type that has a public property of type `ICommand` named `ViewCommand` in it.

If any of these conditions are not true, then your `ICommand` will not work and you will need to meet these conditions. Otherwise, it seems as though you are correctly passing the `DataContext` value through to the `ContextMenu` correctly.